# Need to reconfigure TPlink MR3420 using as repeater after every power shutdown

Tags: router, repeater

I have configured TPlink MR3420 as repeater & its working fine, but after every power cut, I have to reconfigure TPlink as repeater, its not connecting to main router automatically.
Devices trying to connect thru this router never obtain IP from main router.

Can anybody help me on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Decent routers maintain their configuration during a short term power outage.  In my experience, this is true for a couple of hours, likely longer. The actual time depends on the router.

You can try updating the firmware on the router, but firmware does not usually correct the power off time resulting in a lost configuration.

Two solutions:

1. Replace the router with a better router that will maintain its configuration. That is likely the best approach here.
2. Install a small UPS to keep the network up during a power failure. I have a Modem, 2 Routers, and an Access Point. The UPS will keep all devices running for about 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, the only condition is main router should be on static channel & extender or secondary router on WDS must select the same channel, I changed my main router setting as below.

1. Change channel to static 9 (earlier it was set to "Auto")
2. Configured the TP-link router on WDS with same channel (channel 9) as on main router.

Now even after power cut, TP-link is connecting to main router after2-3 mins of power restore.